# REST API load testing with Jmeter

Tags: api, rest, testing, jmeter

Im new to REST API testing, I want to do a load of an HTTP REST API, is there any possibility to do a 100 number of parallel HTTP request testing with Jmeter?

And also my request need a query params, can I provide a list of values to Jmeter and Jmeter can loop each request with one param form the list provided?

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JMeter executes requests as fast as it can, I don't fully understand your `100 number of parallel HTTP request` stanza.

- If you want 100 virtual users concurrently accessing your API endpoint: under [Thread Group](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Thread_Group) specify number of threads as `100` and set loop count to `Forever` or `-1`. In this case the actual number of requests per second will depend on your application response time
- If you want to send 100 requests at exactly the same moment - use [Synchronizing Timer](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeter-synchronizing-timer)
- If you need to send 100 requests per second - use [Precise Throughput Timer](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Precise_Throughput_Timer)

For parameterizing your request with external data people normally use [CSV Data Set Config](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#CSV_Data_Set_Config)